# Dinstances from closed subsets to points in $R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ be a non-empty closed subset of $R$, let $b$ be in $R$ prove that there is an $a$ in $A$ so that $|a-b|=inf|x-a|$. Is $a$ unique?

Edited: forgot to add some details

Comment: what is $b$?...

Comment: I dont even see how this is true, I mean.. cant we take $[0,1]$  and $5$? $Inf|x-a|$ will always be smaller then $|a-b|$?

Comment: Probably it should be $\inf_{x \in A}|x-b|$?

Comment: Ahh so that's what's wrong with the problem

Comment: For uniqueness, think about the midpoint of two given points.